# MSXML adds default empty xmlns to all elements

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, msxml6

I need to create an XML out of an specific xsd schema, and im useing VBA for access with the MSXML2 library. so far i can create everything but the thing is MSXML2 create default xmlns on the fields after the root even tho i specified it.

What i want to achieve:

```
<auditfile xmlns="urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-CashRegister:DK">
  <header>
  </header>
  <company>
  </company>
</auditfile>
```

what im getting:

```
<auditfile xmlns="urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-CashRegister:DK">
  <header xmlns="">
  </header>
  <company xmlns="">
  </company>
</auditfile>
```

I have an validator i can check against everything is ok, but it as soon that the xmlns="" is present i says no.

My code for generateing the start of the xml is like this.

```
Dim Document As Object
Set Document = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

Dim AuditRoot As Object
Set AuditRoot = Document.createElement("auditfile")
AuditRoot.setAttribute "xmlns", "urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-CashRegister:DK"
Document.appendChild AuditRoot

Set headerRoot = Document.createElement("header")
AuditRoot.appendChild headerRoot

Set companyRoot = Document.createElement("company")
AuditRoot.appendChild companyRoot

'Save the XML file
Document.Save "c:\Diamond\XML\SAT-T.xml"
'Set export to be c:\Diamond\XML\fil
MsgBox "File created at dafault location: C:\Diamond\XML\SAT-T.xml"
```

But as said above its different.
so anyhelp to general if i can disable it or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use `.createNode()` method instead of `.createElement()`.

It has 3 parameters, and one of them allows to specify a namespace.

For the reference: [createNode Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757901(v=vs.85))

I used vbscript syntax, but you can easily adjust it back to VBA.

**vbscript**

```
Dim Document
Set Document = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

Dim AuditRoot, NS
NS = "urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-CashRegister:DK"

Set AuditRoot = Document.createNode(1, "auditfile", NS)
Document.appendChild AuditRoot

Set headerRoot = Document.createNode(1, "header", NS)
AuditRoot.appendChild headerRoot

Set companyRoot = Document.createNode(1, "company", NS)
AuditRoot.appendChild companyRoot

'Save the XML file
Document.Save "c:\Diamond\XML\SAT-T.xml"
'Set export to be c:\Diamond\XML\fil
MsgBox "File created at dafault location: C:\Diamond\XML\SAT-T.xml"
```

**Output**

```
<auditfile xmlns="urn:StandardAuditFile-Taxation-CashRegister:DK">
    <header/>
    <company/>
</auditfile>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm. Works way better and can actually use the validator for it now as well.